# Database first , How to implement inheritance in EF6

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to implement inheritance using entity framework 6.0 and database first approach. The reason I want to implement inheritance is because I want to add these below fields in all of my tables.

They are :(**Actually in the common database design, We always add these audit field**. )

- CreatedBy
- CreatedTime
- ModyfiedBy
- ModyfiedTime

I knew **TPT** (table-per-type) is one of the ways to make it. But I don't think **TPT** is the right way to solve my problem. Because TPT need create a table for the Base type. But in my case I think it is not necessary.  Is there any way to make it ? Thanks.

Comment: Please tell my why downvote my question . Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would suggest that database inheritance/TPT/TPH is not necessary for this situation. What you need is just an `IAuditable` interface:

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }

    DateTimeOffset CreatedTime { get; set; }

    string ModifiedBy { get; set; }

    DateTimeOffset? ModifiedTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then you have two options:

1. If you are sure all of your entities will be `IAuditable`, you can simply change the T4 template so that all auto-generated entities will implement `IAuditable`.
2. If only **some** of your entities will be `IAuditable`, you can add partial classes to those auditable entities like:

   ```
   public partial class Foo
   {
       // Auto-generated properties by EF
       public int Id { get; set; }
       ...
   }
   ```

   Then in another file:

   ```
   public partial class Foo : IAuditable
   {
       // No implementation because auditable fields already exists
   }
   ```

You can then derive an abstract class from `DbContext` to automatically update these `IAuditable` properties:

```
public abstract class AuditableDbContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        UpdateAuditableProperties();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync()
    {
        UpdateAuditableProperties();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        UpdateAuditableProperties();
        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected virtual void UpdateAuditableProperties()
    {
        var now = DateTimeOffset.Now;
        var userName = GetUserName();
        var changedAuditableEntities = from entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<IAuditable>()
                                       let state = entry.State
                                       where
                                           state.HasFlag(EntityState.Added) ||
                                           state.HasFlag(EntityState.Modified)
                                       select entry;

        foreach (var auditable in changedAuditableEntities)
        {
            var entity = auditable.Entry;

            switch (auditable.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entity.CreatedDate = now;
                    entity.CreatedBy = userName;
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entity.ModifiedDate = now;
                    entity.ModifiedBy = userName;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected abstract string GetUserName();
}
```

Your `DbContext` can derive from `AuditableDbContext` and then implement `GetUserName()` to supply the username  who creates/modifies the entities.

Comment: :) yeah . Right . I just search something similar in the google. (EF + audit fileds) . your answer help me lot . Thanks. +++1

Comment: Could you please share some code of how to insert or update an entity ? especially for these audit fields. Thanks.

Comment: wow.. Very nice . But , Have you ever think of how to make it in the edmx designer ? I mean maybe it need to change the generated code of entity inherit from the `IAuditable` when the edmx updated. Is there any possibility to do that ? Thanks.

Comment: As I mentioned in my first option, you can change the T4 template which generates the entities. Normally it has an extension of `.tt` which resides next to your `.edmx` file

Comment: yeah .. That should be the way to make it . I just test it in the entity framework 6. .tt file is the code generation template file. That is it works for. :) Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86672/discussion-between-rexcfnghk-and-joe-wang).